# Named pipe client throw UnauthorizedAccessException when calling SetAccessControl

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I am trying to write named pipe client with c#, but I get `UnauthorizedAccessException` when `SetAccessControl()` is invoked.

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity.Persist(SafeHandle handle)
   at NamePipeEx.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\zangw\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NamePipeEx\NamePipeEx\Program.cs:line 27
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()}
```

and here are my codes

```
    PipeAccessRule pr = new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
    PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
    ps.AddAccessRule(pr);
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "logpipe", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
    // connect to the server
    client.Connect();
    client.SetAccessControl(ps);
    client.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
```

Please help me to figure out the failure reason of my codes.

**Edit** add named pipe server code in C++

```
HANDLE hPipe;
LPTSTR lpPipeName = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\logpipe");

// try to open a named pipe
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(lpPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE|PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE|PIPE_WAIT, 
                        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 2048, 2048, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);

if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    printf("Pipe handler error");
    //return -1;
}

if (!ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL)){
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED){
        printf("FAILED to connect ");
    }
}

printf("Client named pipe connected...");
// send message to named pipe

LPTSTR msg = TEXT("Default message from server...\r\n");
DWORD cbToWrite = lstrlen(msg) + 1;

while (true){
    DWORD cbWritten = 0;
    bool fSuccess = WriteFile(hPipe, msg, cbToWrite, &cbWritten, NULL);
    if (!fSuccess)
        printf("Failed to writefile pipe");
}
```

Comment: From document - The current process does not have access to open the file. .. Try with another file

Comment: Exception is still thrown with another file

Answer (score 0):

Because with default security descriptor,  only the administrator or system user can connect to the pipe.

> The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a named pipe grants full control to the LocalSystem account, administrators, and the creator owner. They also grant read access to members of the Everyone group and the anonymous account. In other words, with NULL as the security attribute, the named pipe cannot be connected with WRITE permission across the network, or from a local client running as a lower integrity level.

To grant EVERYONE all access (not just the connect access) to the server, you need to [fill the security attributes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34073/Inter-Process-Communication-IPC-Introduction-and-S).

Answer (score 0):

I solve it when another constructor of `NamedPipeClientStream` with `PipeAccessRights` is used.

```
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "logpipe", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, 
        PipeOptions.WriteThrough, System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.None, HandleInheritability.None);
```

Comment: I was unable to find this constructor. What version of .net is this found in?

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar issues:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

When my server define the pipe direction as `PipeDirection.In` and my client define it with `PipeDirection.In` too (one must be `PipeDirection.Out`, or use `PipeDirection.InOut`if both need to read/write).

I answer here because the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is not always for Security problems, and maybe can help others.